# Improve edge detection using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

so I am working on a project to scan analog photos. The program should detect the edges and crop it automatically. For that I am using Python and OpenCV. My problem is that sometimes my program can not detect the photo as a whole rectangle due to gaps. Here is an example:

[image: example]

This is the codepart where I am using canny:

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # convert the image to gray scale
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (1, 1), 0) # Add Gaussian blur to remove noise
edged = cv2.Canny(blur, 75, 200) # Apply the Canny algorithm to find the edges
```

I also noticed that tweaking up the blur parameters only makes it more inaccurate with finding the edges.

The program seems to work when the colour at the border of the photo is different compared to the surface.

Is there any way to improve the code so it is way more accurate in detecting the edges of a photo?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at how to detect rectangles/documets with Hough lines, e.g. 
https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/document-scanner-using-opencv-houghlines-approach-eb276dd4a0a

Comment: This question and answer may help: https://answers.opencv.org/question/67150/using-minarearect-with-contour-in-python/

Comment: decent image acquisition always helps. your image acquisition (taking the photo) gives a bad picture. lighting is all uneven, the printed photo isn't lying flat on the table, ...